# Change parent state inside react child on input change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following parent component:

```
   class NewPetForm extends React.Component {
     state = {
       name: '',
       age: '',
       animal: '',
       breed: ''
       };

    render() {

    return (
      <StyledNewPetForm >
        <Input label="name" />
        <Input label="age" />
        <Input label="animal"/>
        <Input label="breed"/>
        <Button type="submit" />
      </StyledNewPetForm>
    );
  }
}
```

And the following child component:

```
  class Input extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <StyledWrapper>
        <StyledInput
          value={this.props.test}
          type="text"
        />
      </StyledWrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

Is it possible to listen to changes in all inputs in children components and update the state accordingly?

What I want to achieve is basically passing handlers to different Inputs and update state dynamically, so there is a possibility to reuse Input component.

```
changeHandler = (event,stateName) =>{
  this.setState({[stateName]:event.target.value]})
}
<Input changed={changeHandler(event,'name')}></Input>
<Input changed={changeHandler(event,'age')}></Input>
<Input changed={changeHandler(event,'breed')}></Input>
// Inside Input
<input onChange={this.props.changed}/>
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve; can you detail the problem and possibly make examples?

Comment: Tried to elaborate a little bit with not working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that, you can pass a function to the child element as a property and call it when a change occurs in the child.

Here is an example:

```
class NewPetForm extends React.Component {
 state = {
   name: ''
 };

 onValueChange(key, event) {
    this.setState({[key]: event.target.value})
 }

 render() {
    return (
      <StyledNewPetForm >
        <Input value={this.state.name} onValueChange={this.onValueChange.bind(this, 'name')} />
      </StyledNewPetForm>
    );
 }
}
```

and the child

```
class Input extends React.Component {
 render() {
     return (
      <StyledWrapper>
        <StyledInput
          onChange={this.props.onValueChange}
          value={this.props.value}
          type="text"
        />
      </StyledWrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

`{[key]: event.target.value}` may seem confusing, is just the new syntax that lets you use a string as a property name in an object literal.

The important part is `onChange={this.props.onValueChange}`, here, I'm calling the parent function `NewPetForm.onValueChange` when the input's value changes.

Comment: Thanks, it works as expected! Seems like I thought in the right direction.